# Compare subselect value with value in master select

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

In MS Access, I have a query where I want to use a column in the outer query as a condition in the inner query:

```
SELECT P.FirstName, P.LastName, Count(A.attendance_date) AS CountOfattendance_date,
       First(A.attendance_date) AS FirstOfattendance_date,
       (SELECT COUNT (*) 
          FROM(SELECT DISTINCT attendance_date 
                FROM tblEventAttendance AS B 
                WHERE B.event_id=8 
                  AND B.attendance_date >= FirstOfattendance_date)
       ) AS total
FROM tblPeople AS P INNER JOIN tblEventAttendance AS A ON P.ID = A.people_id
WHERE A.event_id=8
GROUP BY P.FirstName, P.LastName
;
```

The key point is `FirstOfattendance_date` - I want the comparison deep in the subselect to  use the value in each iteration of the master select.  Obviously this doesn't work, it asks me for the value of `FirstOfattendance_date` when I try to run it.

I'd like to do this without resorting to VB code... any ideas?

Comment: What is the complex sub-query in the select-list meant to count?  It isn't clear, but it might be the number of times the person has attended Event_ID 8 after the first day on which they attended Event_ID 8.  We can't tell whether someone can attend multiple times on one day, amongst other things.

Comment: That's exactly it - We want to count the total attendance of possible dates after they first attended, which may not be when the event started.  Assume only one attendance per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT 
     p.FirstName,
     p.LastName,
     Count(a.attendance_date) AS CountOfattendance_date,
     First(a.attendance_date) AS FirstOfattendance_date,
     c.total
FROM (
     tblPeople AS p 
INNER JOIN tblEventAttendance AS a ON 
     a.people_id = p.ID) 
INNER JOIN (SELECT people_id, Count (attendance_date) As total
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT people_id,attendance_date
                FROM tblEventAttendance) 
            Group By people_id) AS c ON 
     p.ID = c.people_id
GROUP BY 
     p.ID, c.total;
```

Comment: That may be getting closer, but it lost the event_id=8 part, and a distinct search for possible dates.  But I think this is on the right track, putting the sub select logic in the from area instead of the select area.

Comment: I don't remember if this was ever resolved, but this answer was on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change

B.attendance_date >= FirstOfattendance_date

to

B.attendance_date >= First(A.attendance_date)

Comment: interesting, but then it says you cannot have an aggregate function in a where clause.

Comment: An aggregate functions can be used as criteria only in the HAVING clause. Since you're using the value from the aggregate correlated subquery, you have to use the alias, as the SELECT statement you're using it in is not an aggregate query.